# How can I narrow down what is catching in my code

Tags: c#, xml, try-catch

So when I originally wrote this up about 6 months ago it was working fine, but now for some reason it catches. I am very new to coding and have no idea how I would narrow it down to find out how to solve this issue. any advice would be greatly appreciated. 
(it is based on a tutorial, and very little has been changed from that tutorial. A few more child nodes added to the saving of the XML.)
If I Set break points on each line after "playerdata.LoadXml..." and before the first "foreach" it skips over maxhp, maxcarry,trouble, and player.CurrentLocation.

```
public static Player CreatePlayerFromXmlString(string xmlPlayerData)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument playerData = new XmlDocument();
            playerData.LoadXml(xmlPlayerData);
            int currenthp = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/CurrentHP").InnerText);
            int maxhp = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/MaxHP").InnerText);
            int gold = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/Gold").InnerText);
            int xp = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/XP").InnerText);
            int lvl = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/Lvl").InnerText);
            decimal currentcarry = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/CurrentCarry").InnerText);
            decimal maxcarry = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/MaxCarry").InnerText);
            int trouble = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/Trouble").InnerText);
            Player player = new Player(currenthp, maxhp, gold, xp, lvl, currentcarry, maxcarry, trouble);
            int currentLocationID = Convert.ToInt32(playerData.SelectSingleNode("/Player/Stats/CurrentLocation").InnerText);
            player.CurrentLocation = World.LocationByID(currentLocationID);
            foreach (XmlNode node in playerData.SelectNodes("/Player/InventoryItems/InventoryItem"))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["ID"].Value);
                int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["Quantity"].Value);
                for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
                {
                    player.AddItemToInventory(World.ItemByID(id));
                }
            }
            foreach (XmlNode node in playerData.SelectNodes("/Player/PlayerQuests/PlayerQuest"))
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["ID"].Value);
                bool isCompleted = Convert.ToBoolean(node.Attributes["IsComplete"].Value);
                PlayerQuest playerQuest = new PlayerQuest(World.QuestByID(id));
                playerQuest.IsComplete = isCompleted;
                player.Quests.Add(playerQuest);
            }
            return player;
        }
        catch
        {
            return Player.CreateDefaultPlayer();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
   Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

This should give you more hint on what's going on.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using `Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline` in place of `Console.Writeline`, but this pointed me directly to the line.
Turns out it did not like the decimal items very much.

Comment: You can use `Int32.TryParse()` when you are unsure about the input.

Answer (score -1):

When you call a `try / catch`, you can specify what you want to catch by specifying the exception you want to catch:

```
try
{
    // do stuff...
}
catch ( Exception e1 )
{
    // do stuff with e1...
    Console.WriteLine(e1.Number + " - " + e1.Message);
}
catch ( AnotherException e2 )
{
    // do stuff with e2...
    Console.WriteLine(e2.Number + " - " + e2.Message);
}
etc...
```